# How to insert an Image .gif file instead of filloval?

Tags: java, image, jframe

I am a newbie on programming, and appreciate your help with this. I created this code and I would  like to replace the `fillOval` with a .gif file/object. What modifications
 should I perform?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {

    int x;
    int y;

    int inix=500;
    int iniy=500;

    int i=0; 
    private void moveBall() {
        /*x = x + 1;
        y = y + 1;*/
        double degrees=(double) i;
        double radians=Math.toRadians(degrees);
        double Sinu=Math.sin(radians);
        double Sinu200=Math.sin(radians)*200;
        int SinuInt=(int) Sinu200;
        //y=500+SinuInt;
        y=iniy+SinuInt;
        double Cos=Math.cos(radians);
        double Cos200=Math.cos(radians)*200;
        int CosInt=(int) Cos200;
        //x=500+CosInt;
        x=inix+CosInt;

        i++;
        if (i==360) i=0;
        //System.out.println(Sinu+"   "+Sinu200+"   "+SinuInt +"   "+x);

    }

    private int sin(double radians) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

        @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);


    }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            game.moveBall();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(3);
        }
    }


    }    >
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`.

To answer your question, use `g.drawImage()`.  Something like this.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.gif"));
        g.drawImage(img, xLocation, yLocation, width, height, this);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

See [Graphics#drawImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)

Comment: Something is not going correctly...(sorry for being dummy) I changed using the following. < @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  //g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
   
  try {
         BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("MyIm.gif"));
         g.drawImage(img, x, y, 100, 100, this);
     } catch (Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
 }>

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: `x` and `y` haven't been initialized in your code. Also make sure the image is in the project root directory

Comment: `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.gif"));`  (grinds teeth) It's a 'personal gripe' of mine to see code that I know we'll later have to fix, and that is a classic example.  This image smacks of an application resource that will later become an [tag:embedded-resource].  As such, it *must* be accessed by URL.  +1 for using the `ImageObserver`.

Comment: I tried this <Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/Images/MyIm.gif");
     g2d.drawImage(img1, x, y, this);> instead of <    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);>

Comment: Look at your other question (post, newest one). I commented a suggestion